# stacking multiband rasters separately

Tags: r, stack, raster

I have the list of multiband raster files( each raster has several bands) and all are in one folder! I only want to take some bands of one file of this folder! How I can do it?
Thanks in advance

Here are the list of my files;

```
  [1] "./2014069_33UXP_04_05_L8_sr_band2.tif" "./2014069_33UXP_04_05_L8_sr_band3.tif" "./2014069_33UXP_04_05_L8_sr_band4.tif"
  [4] "./2014069_33UXP_04_05_L8_sr_band5.tif" "./2014069_33UXP_04_05_L8_sr_band6.tif" "./2014069_33UXP_04_05_L8_sr_band7.tif"
  [7] "./2014085_33UXP_04_05_L8_sr_band2.tif" "./2014085_33UXP_04_05_L8_sr_band3.tif" "./2014085_33UXP_04_05_L8_sr_band4.tif"
 [10] "./2014085_33UXP_04_05_L8_sr_band5.tif" "./2014085_33UXP_04_05_L8_sr_band6.tif" "./2014085_33UXP_04_05_L8_sr_band7.tif"
 [13] "./2014092_33UXP_04_05_L8_sr_band2.tif" "./2014092_33UXP_04_05_L8_sr_band3.tif" "./2014092_33UXP_04_05_L8_sr_band4.tif"
 [16] "./2014092_33UXP_04_05_L8_sr_band5.tif" "./2014092_33UXP_04_05_L8_sr_band6.tif" "./2014092_33UXP_04_05_L8_sr_band7.tif"
 [19] "./2014108_33UXP_04_05_L8_sr_band2.tif" "./2014108_33UXP_04_05_L8_sr_band3.tif" "./2014108_33UXP_04_05_L8_sr_band4.tif"
 [22] "./2014108_33UXP_04_05_L8_sr_band5.tif" "./2014108_33UXP_04_05_L8_sr_band6.tif" "./2014108_33UXP_04_05_L8_sr_band7.tif"
 [25] "./2014117_33UXP_04_05_L8_sr_band2.tif" "./2014117_33UXP_04_05_L8_sr_band3.tif" "./2014117_33UXP_04_05_L8_sr_band4.tif"
```

and for example I want to take the band 2,3,4 and 8 from one file!

Comment: Use regex on your filelist:  `grepl("band[2348]",yourList)`

Comment: Ok I could do it in other way! I substring the dates and then splited the list by dates! it worked!